# Windows Azure websites https

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If I create an azure website let's assume: `myname.azurewebsites.net`, I can access this by using http (`http://myname.azurewebsites.net`) or https (`https://myname.azurewebsites.net`).

What does this mean? Did I understood it right that basically I don't need an SSL certificate as it has one by default?

I need to build a web service that needs to use SSL. Therefore do I need to buy an ssl certificate and custom domain (not important)? I don't need a custom domain and the default one works fine for me. So can I use my service over SSL provided by Azure: `https://myname.azurewebsites.net` (is a wildcard certificate)?

Answer (score 7):

If you need to build a web service that needs to use SSL I highly suggest that you use your own domain and your own SSL certificate (buy one) if you are going **in production** with it. If you just test/play around - than you can safely use the default provided one.

And you are correct about default provided one - you get a (free) SSL for your azure web site as long as it is only bound to the default `XXX.azurewebsites.net` domain. However the certificate you get there is a wildcard certificate issued to `*.azurewebsites.net`. I would not use it if I have to go for a production service!

If you are to use SSL features of Azure Web Sites with your own domain and certificate, check out the [Pricing and requirement pages](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/#service-ssl). There are important things to note!

Comment: Are there any risks if I use the wildcard one xxx.azurewebsites.net? The service will be used for REST (CRUD) calls, there will be no web-site at https://xxx.azurewebsites.net (so users will not browse to it), just some calls from other system that have to be over ssl.

Comment: simple DNS spoofing - an attacker with a valid Azure Web Site `[yyy].azurewebsites.net` can spoof requests from your "other system" and pretend to be your web site. Thus collecting data, which apparently shouldn't be available to third parties since you have the requirement for SSL. There are probably a dozen other risks. But to I think my answer completely covers the scope of your original posted question.